# Should index page be the first page or the login page? what is the best practice?

Tags: php, html, directory

What is the best practice followed when the login page is the first page?

Should the *login page* be renamed to *index page*?

Or should the *first page after logging in* be named index.html?

In my project, Only members can use the site so u have to log in.. and the login page is the first page...!
(Something like you see in gmail !!)

Additional details: I'm working using php,html and Qcubed,in Ubuntu 12.01

Comment: You can display any other file rather than index file as first page using `htaccess` on `apache` server.

Comment: I edited my question so that it may not look opinion based...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index page is typically your home page. Of course that page can redirect to a login page or just render the login widget without redirecting, but often websites allow people to remain logged in (by using a cookie), so in that case you don't even need the login page at all.

Note that in many websites all requests go through index.php, even though it doesn't seem so. There is one entry to the site, which parses the url and executes the right piece of code, which could as well be rendering a login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirect, if user hasn't already logged in. Also, you can safe user info in SESSION or COOKIES therefore user will log in without second authtorisation.

Comment: I'm sorry , but i didnt understand !!

Comment: If your user hasn't logged in, just redirect him to the login page. After he logged into your site, it redirects him to your index page.